# LEFT JOIN doesn't working

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 taxonomies: `city` and `street`.

I need to get `postmeta` for one of my plugins.

Working code for only one taxonomy:

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->postmeta
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'rwp_rating%'
  AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'city'
       AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '2')
```

but if I append

```
AND ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'street' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '5')
```

it returns empty result.

Also I tried to do that:

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->postmeta
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS t1 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS t2 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'rwp_rating%'
  AND (t1.taxonomy = 'city'
       AND t1.term_id = '2')
  AND (t2.taxonomy = 'street'
       AND t2.term_id = '3331');
```

And it doesn’t working too.

Please Note: I need to match both, like: `city = 2 AND street = 2`
not: `city = 2 OR street = 2`

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table conditions in the ON clauses to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt will not work because a single taxonomy record can not have both street and city in it.

Update your second attempt to this :

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as t1 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id AND t1.taxonomy = 'city') 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as t2 ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id AND t2.taxonomy = 'street') 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'rwp_rating%' AND t1.term_id = '2' AND t2.term_id = '3331');
```

Comment: Thank you, but this only works separately too.
Not working: t1.term_id = '2' AND t2.term_id = '3185';
Working: t1.term_id = '2';
Working: t2.term_id = '3185';
Working: t1.term_id = '2' OR t2.term_id = '3185';